# Transforming an SQL table using Unpivot

Tags: sql, database, unpivot, union-all

If I have a table with the following structure

**ID NAME A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3**

X----Y------0---1---2---3---4---5   (dashes are just to push values under headers)

How do I transform it to be the following:

**ID NAME LETTER 1 2 3**

X----Y----------A------0-1-2

X---Y------------B-----3-4-5

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name, 'A' letter, a1 1, a2 2, a3 3 from example_table
UNION
SELECT id, name, 'B' letter, b1 1, b2 2, b3 3 from example_table
```

I'm not sure that `1,2,3` will work as column names; that may be RDBMS-dependant.

Comment: I don't plan on using 1 2 3, they are just example names for now. I will throw my real column names in on my end :)

Is there no way to do it more generically? Getting the column names from Sys cols or something? I have to hardcode each one into a union statement...?

Comment: That sounds like a new question to me. In that question, I (or an answerer with my general level of knowledge) would need to know which RDBMS you are using and to see examples of multiple instances you wish to generalize your procedure toward.

Comment: Also possibly pertinent, whether you are bound to pure SQL or could use a procedural language (PL/SQL, TSQL, etc) for your project.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't consider this a feasible answer, it may give you something to think about as it produces the end result in sql server.

```
SELECT 
    upvt.id
    , upvt.name
    , left(label,1) AS letter
    , CASE
        WHEN left(label,1) = 'A' THEN MIN(value)
        WHEN left(label,1) = 'B' THEN MAX(value)
        END AS [1]
    , CASE
        WHEN left(label,1) = 'A' THEN MIN(value1)
        WHEN left(label,1) = 'B' THEN MAX(value1)
        END AS [2]
    , CASE
        WHEN left(label,1) = 'A' THEN MIN(value2)
        WHEN left(label,1) = 'B' THEN MAX(value2)
        END AS [3]
FROM example_table
UNPIVOT (
    value
    FOR label IN (a1,b1)
    ) upvt
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                id
                , name
                , left(label1,1) AS letter
                , value1
            FROM example_table
            UNPIVOT (
                value1
                FOR label1 IN (a2,b2)
                ) upvt1 ) as b
    ON upvt.id = b.id
    AND upvt.name = b.name
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                id
                , name
                , left(label2,1) AS letter
                , value2
            FROM example_table
            UNPIVOT (
                value2
                FOR label2 IN (a3,b3)
                ) upvt2 ) c
    ON upvt.id = c.id
    AND upvt.name = c.name
group by upvt.id, upvt.name, upvt.label
```

Not exactly what I would call "production ready".